# cakePHP 2.3.1: hasMany through more than 2 tables

Tags: cakephp-2.3

I have a problem with Model relationships and I´m not sure whether I should use hasMany through or an other technique. I´m trying to create an app for creating surveys. I have following relations:

```
Topics hasMany Quests
Quests hasMany Questoptions
```

But when I´m trying to access the Topic Model through the TopicsController I only get the Topics and the linked Quests, not the Questoptions. When I access the Quest Model, I get all Quests and the linked Questoptions. How can I get all Topics with linked Quests and linked Questoptions in one Array?

hasMany through doesn´t seem to be the answer due to it´s not a many to many situation...

Any ideas?

Comment: Ok, i figured it out by myself. I had to give the find-method a param array with `recursive` = `2` ... like

    $this->set('topics', $this->Topic->find('all', array('recursive' => 2)));

Answer (score 0):

Yep, recursive will do the job, but you'd be best of using the Containable Behaviour: http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/containable.html

Basically, setting recursive sets a level that Cake will apply to ALL relationships in that model - and can therefore lead to you getting more data back than you really need, and making your app slower than it could be.

Containable is more fine-grained and lets you select exactly which related data you do and don't want back, for any given request to the database.